# Ld emulator on azure

Tags: android-emulator

I am having problem while installing ld emulator on azure it is saying opengl version is low do i need to choose a different server for le emulator.

I am using windows 10 vcpu 2 core and 16 gb ram.

Can we go in bios or not of azure to turn on other feature